# node js "mssql" request query identify if a row was deleted or not

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm deleting a row with node.js module `mssql`.

```
new sql.Request().query('DELETE FROM OperatingInformationEntries WHERE ID=' + id).then(function (recordset) { });
```

If I try to delete a an ID that does not exist, how do I know that no row was deleted?

Comment: Please provide a link to the library `mssql`

Comment: `new sql.Request().query('DELETE FROM OperatingInformationEntries WHERE ID=' + id).then(function (recordset) { }).catch(function(err) {});` Maybe catching it might help. Did u try?

Comment: yes i tried that, it does not cathc an error, the query is not actually wrong, it should just returns rowAffected = 0, but i cant seem to get that value..

Comment: I guess you are using node-mssql https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#affected-rows

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. 
I write the solution for anyone else who will read this question.

```
let request = new sql.Request();
request.query('DELETE FROM OperatingInformationEntries WHERE ID=' + id).then(function () { 
request.rowsAffected});
```